# Cocos3D - How to load a CC3Texture in background

Tags: load, textures, background-process, cocos3d

I have an array of texture filenames that I want to load in background, and assign them to their corresponding CC3MeshNode when each texture is finished loading, like this:

```
NSArray *fileNames = @[@"MyTexture.png", @"OtherTexture.png"];

for (CC3MeshNode *meshNode in nodesWithTexture) {
    int index = *meshNode.userData;
    NSString *textureFileName = [fileNames objectAtIndex:index];

    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImageAsync: textureFileName withBlock:^(CCTexture2D *tex){
        CC3Texture *texture = [CC3Texture textureFromFile: textureFileName];    //<— SIGABRT with the error described bellow

        // this other alternative won't work because the inner CCTexture2D is a readonly property
        //   |
        //   V
        // CC3Texture *texture = [CC3Texture new];
        // teture.texture = tex;

        meshNode.texture = texture;
    }];
}
```

The problem is that creating a CC3Texture in the bock effectively tries to load the texture again even when it is already in the texture cache:

**[ERROR] CC3PVRTexture ‘MyTexture.pvr':3 cannot be added to the texture cache 
because the cache already contains a texture named MyTexture.pvr. Remove it first before adding another.**

Also assigning the already loaded `CCTexture2D *tex` being passed to the block to a new `CC3Texture *texture` won't work because the property `texture` is readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use the same textures with both **Cocos3D** and *Cocos2D*? If so, it's important that you load the texture as a **Cocos3D** `CC3Texture`. This is because  **Cocos3D** has additional requirements for managing and configuring textures.

You can then access the *Cocos2D* `CCTexture` texture via the `ccTexture` property of the `CC3Texture`. The `CC3DemoMashUpScene addTelevision` method contains some code at the end that you can uncomment to demonstrate the use of the `CC3Texture ccTexture` property.

If you only need the texture for **Cocos3D**, then just load it using one of the `CC3Texture` class-side creation methods. It will be cached automatically.

Regarding loading in the background, remember that you must do so via `CC3Backgrounder` in order to keep the GL context sane. You can do that via something like:

```
[CC3Backgrounder.sharedBackgrounder runBlock: ^{ --load some stuff-- }];
```

The `CCDemoMashUpScene onOpen` method demonstrates using `CC3Backgrounder` to perform a large amount of background loading. You can only perform background loading once the GL view has been established.

Comment: I used a combination of both `CC3OpenGL.renderThread runBlockAsync` to load the texture and `CC3Backgrounder.sharedBackgrounder runBlock` to update the node when finished loading the texture.